# Why K-fold cross validation will built K+1 models?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I have read the general step for K-fold cross validation under
https://machinelearningmastery.com/k-fold-cross-validation/

It describe the general procedure is as follows:

1. Shuffle the dataset randomly.
2. Split the dataset into k groups (folds)
3. For each unique group:Take the group as a hold out or test data set
4. Take the remaining groups as a training data set Fit a model on the training set and evaluate it on the test set
5. Retain the evaluation score and discard the model
6. Summarize the skill of the model using the sample of model
   evaluation scores

So if it is K-fold then K models will be built, right? But why I read from the following link from H2O which is saying it built K+1 models?

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/tutorials/gbm/gbmTuning.ipynb

Comment: Nitpick: it is K-fold, not K folder. Like "twofold" or "tenfold", but with K instead of two/ten. Nothing to do with folders.

Comment: @Amadan nice catch, I am editing accordingly...

Comment: When editing your question *after* an answer has been added, it's good practice to indicate so, as well as to leave a comment to the respondent; it would also be nice to indicate *where exactly* such a reference is made (the linked document is rather long), or even better quote it here... In any case, the answer should already have resolved your question, so kindly accept it (or leave specific feedback if it has not) - thanks...

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have added exactly where I have read the statement for K + 1

Comment: Pls see comment above; "exactly" is an exaggeration - you have linked to a rather *huge* document, and I just couldn't find the exact reference...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably, "I read somewhere else" is too vague a statement (where?), because *context* does matter.

Most probably, such statements refer to some libraries which, by default, after finishing the CV proper procedure, go on to build a model on the whole training data using the hyperparameters found by CV to give best performance; see for example the relevant [`train` function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-80/topics/train) of the `caret` R package, which, apart from [performing CV](https://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#basic-parameter-tuning) (if requested), returns also the `finalModel`:

> finalModel
>
> A fit object using the best parameters

Similarly, scikit-learn [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) has also a relevant parameter `refit`:

> **refit : *boolean, or string, default=True***
>
> Refit an estimator using the best found parameters on the whole dataset.
>
> [...]
>
> The refitted estimator is made available at the `best_estimator_` attribute and permits using `predict` directly on this `GridSearchCV` instance.

But even then, the models fitted are almost never just K+1: when you use CV in practice for hyperparameter tuning (and keep in mind that there there are other uses, too, for CV), you will end up fitting `m*K` models, where `m` is the length of your hyperparameters combination set (all K-folds in a single round are run with one single set of hyperparameters).

In other words, if your hypeparameter search grid consists of, say, 3 values for the no. of trees and 2 values for the tree depth, you will fit `2*3*K = 6*K` models during the CV procedure, and possibly +1 for fitting your model at the end to the whole data with the best hyperparameters found.

So, to summarize:

- By definition, each K-fold CV procedure consists of fitting just K models, one for each fold, with fixed hyperparameters across all folds
- In case of CV for hyperparameter search, this procedure will be repeated for each hyperparameter combination of the search grid, leading to `m*K` fits
- Having found the best hyperparameters, you may want to use them for fitting the final model, i.e. 1 more fit

leading to a total of `m*K + 1` model fits.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I have added where I have read the K+1 statement. 
based on your explanation, it seems for each folder, the model will have different hyper parameters. I though they will be the same set of hyper parameters based on the ones we set when we initialize the model, for example tree depth, number of tree, etc. The difference for each folder is the tree structure due to different data set. Is that right? Or I miss understand the concept

Comment: @Gavin no, each fold is fitted with fixed hyperparameters, for different hyperparameter values you just repeat the whole K-fold procedure - see updated answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply. If you search for the link I added. You will see it says "nfolds+1 models will be built for every set of parameters" which means if m is the hyper parameters length. It will built m*(K+1) instead of m*K + 1. Also for the extra model in each iteration, I feel it is just use the same set of hyper parameter as the rest K folders to fit the entire data set to calculate the train sample AUC for example. Then each grid search will have a train AUC to compare. But I am not quite sure.

Comment: @Gavin saw it; not sure what exactly they mean, and their text is not itself very clear. Calculating the AUC on the train set, as you say, doesn't make much sense; if they fit the model on the whole data in order to measure performance on the *test* set, then it is just wrong procedure (you only use the test set once, for performance assessment of your final model)...

Comment: @Gavin As a general rule you may want to keep in mind that such posts (even from "official" sources) must not be treated as "gospels": [this post of mine](https://www.nodalpoint.com/not-perform-feature-selection/), where I explain in detail a classic mistake in the CV procedure made in a Revolution Analytics blog post (acquired by Microsoft) may be useful as an example...

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and sharing your blog. I have found the explanation in H2O document below:http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/cross-validation.html#how-cross-validation-is-calculated

Comment: @Gavin you mean, you have *confirmed* my explanation in the docs... :)

Comment: Sorry for confusion. what I mean is I found how H2O explain why the package is create K + 1 for each iteration of grid search.